# How to buy a building and update individual sections of one state using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im making an idle clicker game for a project. you buy a building from a list in state that i map and display. if you click the buy button you get one.
im really close i can feel it. I want to set up my buildings state with how many i own and the effect they each have. How can i update my state so that only the one building i click buy from is added.
i know it has something to do with ...state, 'then add new stuff' but i cant get it to work. so i have taken my code to a simple working version. you can click the buy button and get all the buiilding details. What next. I get the building list from a json file i made.

```js
  const [buildingsList, setBuildingsList] = useState([])
  const [buildingsOwned, setBuildingsOwned] = useState({
    buildingOne: 0,
    buildOneBonus: 100,
    buildingTwo: 0,
    buildingTwoBonus: 1000,
    buildingThree: 0,
    buildingThreeBonus: 10000
  })

  const buyBuilding = (building) => {
    console.log('building', building);
  }

<LeftMenu buildingsList={buildingsList} buyBuilding={buyBuilding} />

  function LeftMenu({ buildingsList, buyBuilding }) {
  return (
    <section className="left-menu">
      <h2>Buildings</h2>
      {buildingsList.map((building, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="item" key={index}>
              <img src={building.url} alt="merchant building" />
              <div>{building.name}</div>
              <div>£{building.cost}</div>
              <div>Owned: 1</div>
              <button onClick={() => buyBuilding(building)}>Buy</button>
            </div>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
}

export default LeftMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, for example buildingOne: 0 and you want to update it as buildingOne: 1

```
setBuildingsOwned(prevState => ({...prevState, buildingOne: prevState.buildingOne+1}))
```

Comment: something almost exactly like that. but it would need to know which building to update incase i end up with 100. im thinking it must be some sort of bulding.id check in the addbuilding function.

Comment: @TomBrock Your example code doesn't make it clear what is your need but you can pass callback function to state setter like this with your additional checks and arguments. If property name will come as an argument then use dynamic property name with square bracket notation.